# Why does it take so long to copy MailItems in Outlook?

Tags: email, outlook, copy, directory

I want to copy MailItems from one Outlook folder to another. 
When I run the following code it takes a long time like i.e. 5 seconds per MailItem even if the MailItems are only mails with few lines < 5kB.

I do this in the folders of an IMAP EMail account.

Sometimes I also get an error that an item can not be moved but only be copied.

What do I do wrong? This should be simple.

Currently the code creates first a copy of the mail in the original folder and then I move this copy. I would prefer to create a copy directly in the destination folder.

If I do this manually by dragging and dropping the mails (holding Ctrl to make a copy) this works fast like maybe 1s for 3 mails.

```
Sub CopyMailsToOtherFolder()
On Error GoTo CopyMailsToOtherFolder_Err
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim TestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Dim objItem As Object   'Note that myItem is declared as type Object so that it can represent all types of Outlook items including meeting request and task request items.

    Dim MsgOrg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MsgCopy As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim lngI As Long

    Set TestFolder = objNS.Folders("Edgar").Folders("Inbox")
    Set OutFolder = objNS.Folders("Edgar").Folders("Inbox").Folders("TestOut")

    Debug.Print "Start: " & Time()
    'For lngI = 1 To TestFolder.Items.Count
    For lngI = 1 To 3
        Set objItem = TestFolder.Items(lngI)
        If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then
            Set MsgOrg = objItem
            Debug.Print " Org: " & MsgOrg.Subject
            Set MsgCopy = MsgOrg.Copy      'Creates copy in original folder
            MsgCopy.Move OutFolder
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print "Done"

CopyMailsToOtherFolder_Exit:
    Debug.Print "Exit: " & Time()
    Exit Sub

CopyMailsToOtherFolder_Err:
    Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume CopyMailsToOtherFolder_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: IMAP4 store provider is notoriously bad - every time you touch an item, it attempts to sync it (and its parent folder) with the remote IMAP4 server. Do you see the same behavior in a PST store?

Comment: I just tried it with a MS Exchange account and that works instantly. The good news for me is that I just tested it first on the IMAP account where I discovered the problem. But in reality I need it for Exchange, so for me the issue is kind of solved. Thanks